# Display button with sharedpreference value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-button

I have editText in Activity. I used SharedPreference for saving this value and get later. I passed this edittext value to another activity button text. Initially i need to hide the button. If edittext values are coming from sharedPreference i need to display the button

code:

Activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                 editor.putString("Name",et.getText().toString());
                 editor.putString("Name1",et1.getText().toString());

                  editor.commit();

                  Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Activity1.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
```

Activity1:

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);

     if(preferences){
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn.setText(preferences.getString("Name", ""));

}
```

And also btn setText with Name and this button having values of Name, Name1 editText values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
String Namestr=(preferences.getString("Name",""));

if(Namestr.length>0){
   btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   btn.setText(preferences.getString("Name", ""));
}
```

i hope its useful to you.

Comment: It's working. But the problem is if i enter text, test then button is created with test text. If i create test1 then button test is replace with test1. I need to show test & test1 with two buttons.

Comment: `btn.setText(preferences.getString("Name", ""));`
instead of 
`button.append(preferences.getString("Name", ""));`

Comment: Im asking how to increase the btn text automatically while text coming from edittext. If i enter test first time i need to show test button. Then i enter test2 second time i need to show test button and test2 button. Now i send two edittext field to button.

Comment: yes. One button for test another for test2. But i need to use only one button with autoincrement. Is it possible?

Comment: use linearlayout and don't take button in xml.uou can create button dynemically and add it in you linear view.

Comment: how? I didn't use before?

Answer (score 0):

Debug this condition Your if(preference) condition is wrong.

```
if(preferences){
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn.setText(preferences.getString("Name", ""));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);

     if(preferences.contains("Name")){
String Namestr=(preferences.getString("Name",""));
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn.setText(Namestr);

}
```

Oki i think first you should have a validation condition while putting into shared preference.
And then use this code. Coz in my case i have edittext hint text so chek it before putting in 
shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear)


SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
String Namestr=(preferences.getString("Name",""));

if(Namestr.length>0){
   Button button = new Button(this);
   btn.setText(preferences.getString("Name", ""));
layout.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: It displays only one button. If i enter test it displays the button with test text, then i enter test2 it replace the test with test2. I don't want to replace text i need to create new  button with test2.